# Whats the default password for puppet users?

Tags: vagrant, puppet

Say that I make a user resource...

```
user { 'test':
  ensure => 'present',
  groups => 'some_group'
}
```

If you vagrant ssh into that machine, what would be the default password for test user -> su test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a newly created user will have no password, and it will not be possible to log in as the user. If you want to set a password, you need to specify the `password` property of the user resource.